# Excel process left after closing Excel instance created by Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am using the code below to export a SQL statement from Access to Excel :-

```
Dim myrs        As DAO.Recordset ' Create a recordset to hold the data
Dim myExcel     As New Excel.Application 
Dim mySheet     As Excel.Worksheet

Set mySheet = myExcel.Workbooks.Add(1).Worksheets(1) 
Set myrs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select...") ' 

With mySheet
    .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset myrs
End With

myExcel.Visible = True
myExcel.WindowState = xlMaximized

Set mySheet = Nothing
Set myExcel = Nothing
```

This all works perfectly. However when I close Excel, an Excel process is left open. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What code are you using to close Excel?  You are clearing the pointers, but not closing/destroying the objects (You aren't even closing the Workbook! e.g `myExcel.Workbooks(1).Close: myExcel.Quit`)

Comment: @Chronocidal I don't want to close Excel from Access. Excel should be closed by the user at a later point. It is after this that the process remains in memory.

Comment: Are there any other Excel objects that you are calling/activating, which you are not clearing?  Or, it could (*potentially*) be caused by the fact that you are early-binding Excel, which may make Access "hold" it open.  Does removing the Reference and changing to Late Binding solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - it works for me:

```
Dim myrs        As DAO.Recordset ' Create a recordset to hold the data
Dim myExcel     As New Excel.Application
Dim myBook      As Excel.Workbook
Dim mySheet     As Excel.Worksheet

Set myBook = myExcel.Workbooks.Add(1)
Set mySheet = myBook.Worksheets(1)
Set myrs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select...") '

With mySheet
    .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset myrs
End With

myExcel.Visible = True
myExcel.WindowState = xlMaximized
```

The Excel instance closes when Excel is manually closed.

Comment: With the addition of Set myExcel = Nothing & Set myBook = Nothing- this works. Thank you.